# Unicode characters from SQLite to HTML

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, unicode, sqlite

I'm building a web page using CGI and Python (yes, I know, horrible combination!). I have some unicode data stored inside my SQLite 3 database, which I load in my Python script. When it's time to combine those unicode characters with HTML, I'm viewing things like this in my web browser:

> \xc3\xb3

Instead of:

```
ó
```

I think the problem isn't in the HTML code, because I have defined the encoding like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

This is how I'm rendering the HTML code (using web.py's templating system):

```
render = web.template.render("templates")
return render.index(name)
```

Where `name` is:

```
name = cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM names").fetchone()
```

And the template (index.html):

```
$def with (name)
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
<head>
    <title>untitled</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    Hello, $name!
</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you interpolating the data into your HTML output?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using web.py's templating system.

Comment: Can you show us your code then?

Comment: And the template, and how you built the data structures you are using in the template. :-)

Comment: Updated :-). That's enough?

Comment: I've checked and the data is stored as `\xc3\xb3` in the database. How can I convert that to `ò` in Python 3? (yes, Python 3 stores the data in the database and Python 2 reads it).

Comment: @cdonts: Make sure the Python 3 code gives the database a `str` rather than a `bytes`. You may have to `decode` in the Python 3 script to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked that and right before the string is stored, `type(name)` returns `str`. Any other idea?